# Foursquare API - Not returning photos

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, foursquare

I have a basic Foursquare API account and I'm using venue search, to:

1. Search for a city location
2. And then return venue results.

Pretty simple.

I'm using this api, but no photos seem to be available in the API feed for photos.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=london&&client_id={MY-API-KEY}&client_secret={MY-SECRET-KEY}&v=201806044

I'm using ReactJS and making a simple axios request for this api.  Code further below...

What's the best way to get photos for a venue?  I search and stackoverflow and tried adding &venuePhotos=1 as suggested previously be a user, but that didn't work...

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('COMPONENT DID MOUNT');

    axios.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=london&&client_id={MY-API-KEY}&client_secret={MY-SECRET-KEY}&v=201806044&venuePhotos=1')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('DATA', res.data.response.groups[0].items);
        this.setState(
          { places: res.data.response.groups[0].items.slice(0,12)}
        );
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning on May 31st, foursquare made five changes in order to simplify their API and maintain the quality of their service as their developer community grows.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/announcements#start-up-tier-launch

> Venues search, explore, trending, similar, and next endpoints will return the following fields: venue name, venue ID, address, lat/long, and category. To access additional rich content for each venue, please call the details (venues/x) endpoint with venue ID as a parameter.

So, you should call the details (venues/x) endpoint.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/details

Comment: What does /x represent?   So the api I've accessed, which includes an array for photos, doesn't actually pull through any photos?

Comment: Also, @KosukeOgawa - doe venues/id only work with an OAUTH?

Comment: `x` means venueId. e.g. https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ac518eff964a52064ad20e3/photos?limit=10&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxx&v=20180602

Comment: @ReenaVerma venues/id work with User or userless authentication. https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication